# cell is nil in prototype cell

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, uitableview

I'm new in iPhone development, I have one problem, my app contains navigation from button click to `tableView` (I Use storyboard). I created custum prototype `cell`, class for it and indentifier. But in my method when i debuged it comes to `cell==nil` and thow exeption:
'`NSInternalInconsistencyException`', reason: 'Could not load `NIB` in bundle

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"transportTableCell";
    CNTransportCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"size of %d",transportArray.count);
    cell.modelLabelView.text =  @"sometext";

if(cell == nil){

   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:
                   @"transportTableCell" owner: self ////options:nil];    
   cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
return cell;
```

}

code for navigate by click to table view:

```
 - (IBAction)searchButtonClick:(id)sender {
    CNJSONParser *parser = [[CNJSONParser alloc]init];
    NSString *url = [parser getURL:@"43" :@"66"];

    CNCarListWindowController *cars = [[CNCarListWindowController alloc]init];
    cars.transportArray = [parser parseJSON:url];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cars animated:TRUE];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

just change your code as below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"transportTableCell";
    CNTransportCell *cell;

if(cell == nil){    
   cell = (CNTransportCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
return cell;
```

Comment: for that take guide for actual proccess of prototype cell in Link http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 and scroll down to "Designing Your Own Prototype Cells"

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are using storyboard and this method you have implemented is used when you use xib.

in storyboard you need to give identifier in "show the attribute inspector" of table view